# UILabel redraws the view. How to avoid this behavior?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uilabel

I have a viewController with three subviews.
Also I use AutoLayout and size classes.
These views are animated and change location and size.
After the animations I update a label but the whole view is redrawn so each view is in their initial position and size. This shouldn't happen.
As in Apple developer reference that says:

> "The default content mode of the UILabel class is
>   UIViewContentModeRedraw. This mode causes the view to redraw its
>   contents every time its bounding rectangle changes. You can change
>   this mode by modifying the inherited contentMode property of the
>   class."

It doesn't seem clear to me how to modify the ***-contentMode-*** in order to update that label and leave the view -as is-. Can anyone give me a clue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the code you're using to animate and update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may be using autolayout to lay out your view (e.g., via constraints in IB), but then you're manipulating your views' `frame`s directly for your animations - is this the case? If so, you should instead be animating the `constant` values of your constraints, or possibly the `transform`s of your subviews.

If you manipulate frames directly in a view which uses autolayout, your changes will be over-written the next time the system lays out your view (e.g. after a label's text changes).

You have 3 options to overcome your issue -

1. Stop using AutoLayout in your Storyboard/Xib.

   *Not a great solution*
2. Animate changes to the `transform` property of your subviews. e.g. `myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0,2.0);`

   *Useful for presentation and dismissal animations, but mixing AutoLayout and transforms has some issues pre-iOS 8.0*
3. Add IBOutlets for the constraints you need to change in your animations. Animate changes to the `constant` values of those constraints.

   *Most robust approach but can lead to a lot of properties and code for complex animations*

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention it, but yes, I am using autolayout for every single thing inside the main view controller (including subviews). And then, I set some parameters within -viewWillAppear- and during execution the views will perform some animations, then the view will not redraw until I call label.text=@"whatever". Thanks for the clue: it must be something about the constant values... Do you thing I should set them programmatically instead of setting those values using the IB? Thanks John.

Comment: And in your animations, are you setting frames directly? If so, that is certainly the source of your problem - see my answer above.

Comment: The animations look like this:

 [UIView animateWithDuration:tiempo delay: 0
   options: (UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear)
   animations:^{
     vista1.frame = CGRectMake(V1x, V1y-160, 80, 140);
     vista2.frame = CGRectMake(V2x, V2y+160, 80, 140);
         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                 [UIView animateWithDuration:tiempo delay:0
                      options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                      animations:^{
  vista1.frame  = CGRectMake(V2x, V1y-160, 80, 140);
  vista2.frame = CGRectMake(V1x, V2y+160, 80, 140);...

Comment: So my assumption was correct - you are attempting to set frames directly in a view that uses auto layout. You should not be doing that. You have 3 options to overcome your problem, which i'll add to my answer.

Comment: Nice approach! I am working on 3rd solution but as mentioned it's going to be a hard time coding. I guess all could be fixed somehow if I could set the new views sizes and locations as pre default so redrawing shouldn't be an issue. I'm not sure if that is possible... but it would be awesome! Thanks again.

Comment: If your animations are one-time only presentation animations, consider option 2 - setting up your IB constraints to lay out the final presented state, then set your views `transforms` in `viewDidLoad` to the initial state, and reset the `transforms` to CGAffineTransformIdentity in an animation block in `viewWillAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

Try contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter. This should prevent the redraw you're seeing. Although that may not be the contentMode you want.

Option 2 is to use CATextLayer to draw the label. It will resize very nicely with animation, but it's a lot more work to set up.

Comment: Thanks Dave. The issue is not animating a Label or its layer. The problem I have is that just changing the label.text value, it redraws the whole view and resets values (size and location) for the subviews (which I am trying to avoid). For the record, next time I'll be using CALayers.